# Issue with accessing form.cleaned_data in Django view function

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm encountering an unexpected issue while working on a Django project involving a registration form. I have two code snippets that are functionally similar, but I'm getting different outcomes regarding the access to `form.cleaned_data`. I'm hoping someone can help me figure out what might be causing this discrepancy.

Code Snippet 1:

```
def signup(req):
if req.method == 'POST':
    form = RegisterForm(req.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        messages.success(req, 'Account Created successfully')
        form.save()
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return render(req, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
else:
    form = RegisterForm()
    return render(req, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Code Snippet 2:

```
def signup(req):
if req.method == 'POST':
    form = RegisterForm(req.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        messages.success(req, 'Account Created successfully')
        form.save()
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return render(req, 'signup.html', {'form': form})

form = RegisterForm()
return render(req, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

In both snippets, the form is submitted and processed similarly. However, when I use the first snippet, I can successfully access form.cleaned_data and print it after a successful form submission. But when I use the second snippet, form.cleaned_data seems to be unavailable, and the printed output is empty.

I have double-checked the code for any typos or missed details, but both snippets are practically identical. I'm quite puzzled as to why this difference in behavior is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet is correct. It maintains the same form instance after a successful submission, allowing you to access `form.cleaned_data` but the second snippet is incorrect. It creates a new form instance after each request, including after successful submission. This prevents you from accessing `form.cleaned_data`.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this statements "It creates a new form instance after each request" Do it change form instance on each changes in the form.  The only changes I made in second snippet is removed the else statement as if it's a post request then it should be returned from the first return statement.